# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting Not Working Properly (applying "is not empty" instead of custom formula)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

This seems like a glitch to me, because I've tried a few things and it does not make sense.

My conditional formatting was supposed to grey out rows if column Q = hold.

Instead, the conditional formatting is applying green to any cell in my range that is not empty.

I've cleared the rules and tried again fresh, and the same thing is happening.

And when I delete the rule, the green cells remain. I tried to reset the color and it will not remove the green.

[image: Picture of formula & cells turning green for wrong rule]

Comment: Did you clear by: Select all -> Format -> Clear Formatting?

Answer (score 2):

conditional formating is priority-wise. previous rule will execute as first. right-click on the upper left corner and go to conditional formatting

[image: 0]

then check if you don't have any "green" rules above your grey rule

Answer (score 0):

If you click on any of the cells that you don't expect to be affected does is show only your rule?

Here is a working example

[image]